# How to calculate hausdroff distance between two meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

Actually I have decimated (ie., reduced the meshes)in the given object using planar option. Now, I need to check the [hausdroff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#:%7E:text=The%20Hausdorff%20distance%20is%20the,point%20in%20the%20other%20set.) between original mesh and decimated mesh.

Comment: Can we ask what you need this _for_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a suitable approximation?

[image]

It'a a Geometry Nodes modifier which returns the maximum distance between 2 meshes, when their object- origins are coincident. Depending on how you want to use this number, it could be stored on the mesh, or used elsewhere.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to achieve this one.

Comment: @DeepakDeep See Edit: That's why I've asked how you want to use this result.. I don't know, it may need to be scripted? What are you going to do with this number?

Comment: Actually based on that, if the max. distance is within limit then I will further proceed with decimation.

Comment: @DeepakDeep, it does sound as if someone should write a script or operator to converge on the right level of decimation to meet your threshold, using a combination of 
 [limited dissolve](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.dissolve_limit) and [find nearest](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.find_nearest). That could automate the search. If this is on the right track, you should edit your question to make that clearer.